# Trying to solve a differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, constants

I am trying to solve the following differential equation

### $$y''=2yy'$$

and ended up with the answer:
$$\frac{1}{C_1}\arctan\frac{y}{C_1}+C_2=x.$$

However, the answer should be,

$$\arctan\frac{y}{C_1}+C_2=x.$$

So I tried manipulating my solution in the following way,

$$\left(\frac{1}{C_1}\right)\left(\frac{y}{C_1}\right)=\tan(x-C_2)$$

$$\left(\frac{y}{C_1}\right)=\tan(x-C_2)$$
$$\arctan\frac{y}{C_1}+C_2=x.$$

Which ends up being the correct answer.

Did I break any law of math in the above steps? Or it can't be done that way? This is the only way I can think of on how my professor come up with such answer.

Comment: Please edit your question and use a title which describes the its content: the purpose of the title is to describe what is being asked.

Comment: @johnny You didn't followup on [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633791/help-about-this-constant#comment5438979_2633791) from yesterday, then why keep reposting the same question [over](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634410/someone-please-check-this-out-im-really-confused-about-this-constants) and again here. Voting to close as a duplicate in both places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first answer is correct.  The later manipulation you performed to get the answer you say your teacher came up with is wrong.
$$
\left(\frac1{C_1}\right)\left(\frac{y}{C_1}\right)=\tan(x-C_2)
$$
does not follow from
$$
\frac1{C_1}\arctan\frac{y}{C_1}+C_2=x
$$

---

Additionally, there are two other answers depending on the sign of the constant of integration of the first integration.

Integrating
$$
y''=2yy'
$$
gives
$$
y'=y^2+c_1
$$
Dividing and integrating yields
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2+c_1}=\int\mathrm{d}x
$$
If $c_1\gt0$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{c_1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)+c_2=x
$$
which gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=a\tan(ax+b)}
$$
If $c_1=0$,
$$
c_2-\frac1y=x
$$
which gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=\frac1{b-x}}
$$
If $c_1\lt0$,
$$
-\frac1{\sqrt{-c_1}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{-c_1}}\right)+c_2=x
$$
which gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=-a\tanh(ax+b)}
$$

Comment: The answer should be expressed in x so it follows the given answer. What im asking is if what I did is legal and didnt break any law of math.

Comment: As you can see we both come up with the same answer after integrating the last part, but that is slightly different from the answer given.

Comment: @robjon Okay then, I will stick to my first answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make the susbtitution
$$u(y)=y'(x)$$
So your differential equations becomes
$$u'(y)\,u(y)=2y\,u(y)\Longleftrightarrow u(y)(2y-u'(y))=0.$$
Solving the above equation will result in:
$$\begin{aligned}&(1)\,u(y)=0,\,\\&(2)\,u'(y)=2y.\end{aligned}$$

For $(2)$:
$$u(y)=2\int y\,dy=2y^2+C_1.$$
Therefore, the solutions for $u$ are:
$$u(y)=\{0,y^2+C_1\}.$$
Substituting back into the initial relation, you have
$$(3)\,y'(x)=0, \qquad (4)\,y'(x)=y^2(x)+C_1$$
The solution to $(3)$ is simply a costant, while $(4)$:
$$y'(x)=y^2(x)+C_1\Longleftrightarrow \frac{dy(x)}{y^2(x)+C_1}=dx$$
and by integrating both sides, you obtain:
$$\operatorname{\LARGE\int}\frac{dy(x)}{\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{C_1}}\right)^2+1}=\operatorname{\LARGE\int} dx\implies\frac1{\sqrt{C_1}}\arctan\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{C_1}}\right)=x+C_2.$$
Solving for $y(x)$ gives
$$y(x)=\sqrt{C_1}\tan\left(x\sqrt{C_1}+C_2\sqrt{C_1}\right).$$